# Salvar valores de ComboBox c#

Tags: c#, combobox

Olá

Sou iniciante no C# e tenho um combobox recebendo dados do mysql:

```
        mConn.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select modelonome from modelo", mConn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable dtModelos = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtModelos);

        cbModelo.DisplayMember = "modelonome";
        cbModelo.ValueMember = "modelocod";
        cbModelo.DataSource = dtModelos;
```

Criei um metodo para salvar no banco de dados:

```
 public void salvar(Config config)
    {
        mConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False; server=localhost;database=****;uid=****;password=*****");


        string comandosql = "INSERT INTO SETUP(setcanal,setporta,setlinha,setposto,setmodelo)" +
            "VALUES(@setcanal,@setporta,@setlinha,@setposto,@setmodelo)";

        MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(comandosql, mConn);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setcanal",config.Setcanal);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setporta", config.Setporta);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setlinha", config.Setlinha);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setposto", config.Setposto);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setmodelo", config.Setmodelo);


        try
        {
            mConn.Open();
            int regitrosAfetados = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            mConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

E estou chamando ele na minha tela no botao:

```
ConfigDB configDB = new ConfigDB();
            Config config = new Config(int.Parse(tbCanal.Text), int.Parse(tbPorta.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cbLinha.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(cbPosto.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(cbModelo.SelectedValue)); 
            configDB.salvar(config);
            MessageBox.Show("Registro salvo com sucesso!");
```

Mas sempre dá o erro: "Unable to cast object of type" e não salva
Alguém sabe o que pode ser? como seria a forma correta de salvar?
Ou de pelo menos como pegar o nome que é exibido?
Já tentei usar o SelectedItem.toString(); mas ele retorna o nome DataROwView alguma coisa assim.

Comment: algum dado não pode ser convertido... primeiro precisa saber que infomação está gerando o *"Unable to cast object of type"*. primeiro coloque os valores em variáveis individuais pra identificar o problema, por exemplo `var canal=int.Parse(tbCanal.Text);`... e assim por diante, veja se todas convertem certo e se batem com os tipo de dados da tabela. Atenção números com milhares e vírgula e datas, fazendo isso vais achar o problema

Comment: Olá. então tbCanal é um textBox ele salva normal, não é nele que tá dando problema de cast, é no comboBox cbLinha, cbPosto e cbModelo

Comment: então veja como converter corretamente esses valores, confira os valores de `SelectedValue` e vais conseguir resolver ;)

Comment: Desaninha o código e veja qual o exato ponto que está dando erro, fica mais fácil de depurar.

Answer (score 0):

Ou esse combobox `cbLinha` ou esse aqui `cbPosto` não tem a propriedade `ValueMember` definido.

Dessa forma seu `SelectedValue` se torna um `System.Data.DataRowView` e por isso da erro na sua conversão do valor para inteiro.

A solução é definir a propriedade `ValueMember` corretamente para um desses dois ComboBox.

Comment: Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.8#coment-rios